# Add CrossOriginFilter to dropwizard using guice

Tags: java, ajax, cross-domain, guice, dropwizard

I am pretty new to dropwizard and guice. When I hit my api from an ajax code locally, I get the following error on my browser's console.
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

After researching the error many people are suggesting adding CrossORiginFilter to my dropwizard code. which is done thru env.addFilter
But I am trying to use Guice. here is my main class

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
{
    new TListService().run( args );
}

@Override
public void initialize( Bootstrap<TListServiceConfiguration> bootstrap )
{
    bootstrap.setName( "tlist" );
    bootstrap.addBundle( GuiceBundle.< TListServiceConfiguration > newBuilder().addModule( new JpaPersistModule( this.getClass().getPackage().getName() ) ).setConfigClass( TListServiceConfiguration.class )
            .enableAutoConfig( this.getClass().getPackage().getName() ).build() );
}

@Override
public void run( TListServiceConfiguration config, Environment env ) throws Exception
{        
}
```

and here is my ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnSend').click(function(){
        var apiUrl = $('#txtServer').val() + $("#selectApi").val();
        console.log("URL: " + apiUrl);
        var postData = JSON.parse($('#textData').val());
        console.log(postData);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(postData));
        $.ajax({
            url: apiUrl,
            async: false,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType:"json",
            contentType:"application/json; charset=UTF-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(postData),
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            console.log("success");
            console.log(data);
        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.error("Error");
        })
        .always(function() {
            console.log("complete");
        });
    });     
});
```

Comment: I don't see much of anything wrong with just using the _Environment_ in this manner. It doesn't save much in terms of injecting it via Guice and doesn't take away from testability.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I guess you're right, I eventually did it using the Environment and it is working just fine. although, I am still trying to get it to work using google-guice.

Comment: I think the one way would be to write a wrapper for the _Application_ itself so that you can _@Inject_ it into a helper method or at least something along those lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had the same problem, wanted to use guice to inject the filters, the solution that was arrived modify the GuiceBudle to accpet filters injection, in our case were still wearing the @WebFilter to do this, otherwise you will have to use the Environment.

In AutoConfig class you can create a addFilters method, which will use the library to look for reflections of all classes annotated with @WebFilter, would be something like this:

```
public void addFilters(Environment env, Injector injector) {
    Set<Class<?>> annotatedClasses = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(WebFilter.class);
    for (Class<?> annotated : annotatedClasses) {
        env.addFilter(injector.getInstance(annotated), annotated.getAnnotation(WebFilter.class).urlPatterns()[0];
    }
}
```

or you can later add the filter in the run method:

```
@Override
public void run( TListServiceConfiguration config, Environment env ) throws Exception {      
    env.addFilter(Filter.class, "urlPatterns");
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain more, or potentially add code? I am very new to dropwizard and guice.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I found another example and it worked for me. it was somewhat similar to your approach.

Answer (score 5):

First, create a filter to allow cross domain requests

```
public class CrossDomainFilter implements Filter {
       public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

            HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

            res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
            res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
            res.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600");

            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
}
```

Then, add mapping in `run()` method of your Service class

`env.getApplicationContext().addFilter(CrossDomainFilter.class, "/*", EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.ERROR));`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. although your answer works, I wanted to use it with guice. that's why I am going to choosing the other answer as the answer for this question.